# What does a red circle on a task mean in an SSIS package?

Tags: ssis, execute-sql-task

I am creating a similar package to this package but I don't know the meaning of the red mark in the pic below:

[image]

Comment: It means debugging is set up

Comment: you can right click task and enable debugging

Comment: I still cannot find the debug option, please let me know where is it?

Comment: I am not sure that you can get to this specific breakpoint the way the answer states. This is a script task. Open the code and remove the breakpoint if needed. But you put a breakpoint in a script task so that you can get a much better error than "the script task failed"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you need to have breakpoints in that task, to have red mark coming in.

See the below steps to enable breakpoints.

Reference: [Breakpoints in SSIS](https://www.tutorialgateway.org/breakpoints-in-ssis/)

1. Go to breakpoints for a task

[image: Breakpoints for a task]

2. Enable breakpoints for specific event

[image: Edit Breakpoints]

Comment: Thank you so much, I also found that I haven't open my package with solution explorer, that's maybe why the option Edit Breakpoint disappeared.